# create a random number less than a max given value

Tags: c, random

What i would love to do is to create a function that takes a parameter that is the limit of which number the random generation should create. I have experienced that some generators that just repeat the number generated over and over again.

How can I make a generator that doesn't return the same number consecutively. Can someone please help me to achieve my goal?

```
int randomGen(int max)
{
  int n;      
  return n;
}
```

Comment: http://www.phanderson.com/C/random.html

Comment: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial39_Random-Number-Generation.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to get uniformly distributed results from `rand` is something like this:

```
int limited_rand(int limit)
{
  int r, d = RAND_MAX / limit;
  limit *= d;
  do { r = rand(); } while (r >= limit);
  return r / d;
}
```

The result will be in the range `0` to `limit-1`, and each will occur with equal probability as long as the values `0` through `RAND_MAX` all had equal probability with the original `rand` function.

Other methods such as modular arithmetic or dividing without the loop I used introduce **bias**. Methods that go through floating point intermediates do not avoid this problem. Getting good random floating point numbers from `rand` is at least as difficult. Using my function for integers (or an improvement of it) is a good place to start if you want random floats.

**Edit**: Here's an explanation of what I mean by bias. Suppose `RAND_MAX` is 7 and `limit` is 5. Suppose (if this is a good `rand` function) that the outputs 0, 1, 2, ..., 7 are all equally likely. Taking `rand()%5` would map 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 to themselves, but map 5, 6, and 7 to 0, 1, and 2. This means the values 0, 1, and 2 are twice as likely to pop up as the values 3 and 4. A similar phenomenon happens if you try to rescale and divide, for instance using `rand()*(double)limit/(RAND_MAX+1)` Here, 0 and 1 map to 0, 2 and 3 map to 1, 4 maps to 2, 5 and 6 map to 3, and 7 maps to 4.

These effects are somewhat mitigated by the magnitude of `RAND_MAX`, but they can come back if `limit` is large. By the way, as others have said, with linear congruence PRNGs (the typical implementation of `rand`), the low bits tend to behave very badly, so using modular arithmetic when `limit` is a power of 2 may avoid the bias problem I described (since `limit` usually divides `RAND_MAX+1` evenly in this case), but you run into a different problem in its place.

Comment: Of course, if `limit > RAND_MAX`, this will result in division by 0. (But maybe that's a good thing to catch cases where you're not truly getting uniform random numbers from the range you want.)

Comment: Yes.. if you're worried that might really happen, you should wrap `rand` with a function that calls `rand` multiple times and appends the bits until you have a uniform distribution on a large known fixed power-of-two range.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
 int randomGen(int limit)
 {
    return rand() % limit;

 }
   /* ... */
 int main()
 {
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%d", randomGen(2041));

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: This common method is incorrect and results in biased random numbers unless `limit` is a power of 2.

Comment: Simple, and the OP makes no mention of the need for ab equal probability of each number.

Comment: It will give biased results even if limit is a power of two if rand is a linear congruential generator.

Comment: Well if the original `rand` has bias, fixing that is much harder... You'd be better off just writing your own.

Comment: @R.: LCG are crappy, but for non-scientific applications, they perform just fine as to their high-order bits. Not their lower order ones though.

Answer (score 0):

Without explicit knowledge of the random generator of your platform, **do not** do `rand() % max`. The low-order bytes of simple random number generators are usually not random at all.

Use instead (returns a number between min inclusive and max non-inclusive):

```
int randomIntegerInRange(int min, int max)
{
    double tmp = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX - 1.);
    return min + (int)floor(tmp * (max - min));
}
```

**Update**: The solution above is biased (see comments for explanation), and will likely not produce uniform results. I do not delete it since it is a non natural example of *what not to do*. Please use rejection methods as recommended elsewhere in this thread.

Comment: @Matt: this works. With other knowledge from rand(), I'd do modulus with a power of 2 and rejection. But here, if rand() is a linear congruential crap, there is no better way.

Comment: This solution does not fix the bias.

Comment: @R. It is very hard to come with a rand() implementation which has bias in its higher order terms. There are problems with modulus, but not with this approach. What bias are you talking about ?

Comment: If `max-min` does not go evenly into `RAND_MAX+1`, some outputs will have more inputs mapping onto them than others.

Comment: @R. In this case, this works fine. I draw a uniform double between 0 and max - min (exclusive). There is no bias at all if rand() yields a uniform integer between 0 and RAND_MAX. This is the whole point of using doubles.

Comment: R is correct, there *is* a bias.  It's a simple pigeonhole principle problem - if you try to map every possible `rand()` value onto an output integer, and the number of possible outputs doesn't exactly divide the number of possible `rand()` values, then some output values will be mapped from less `rand()` values than others.  Hence, bias.

Comment: @Alexandre: you do not draw a uniform double between 0 and `max-min` using that algorithm. The probability distribution for resulting doubles has weight **zero** on the vast majority of possible doubles in that range, with nonzero spikes here and there. Each of the spikes has equal probability `1/(RAND_MAX+1)`, but when you rescale to map to an integer, different numbers of these spikes get mapped onto different integers, giving bias.

Comment: @R., @caf. Understood. I never thought about that issue (the bias is little, but probably statistically significant). Usually, I use rejection on the low order bits of a *known* rng.

Answer (score 0):

Any pseudo-random generator will repeat the values over and over again with some period. C only has `rand()`, if you use that you should definitively initialize the random seed with `srand()`. But probably your platform has better than that.

On POSIX systems there is a whole family of functions that you should find under the `man drand48` page. They have a well defined period and quality. You probably find what you need, there.