# how to randomly print 1 to 10 in C

Tags: c, random

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Generate Random numbers uniformly over entire range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-entire-range)
>   [In C, how do I get a specific range of numbers from rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202687/in-c-how-do-i-get-a-specific-range-of-numbers-from-rand)

i want to generate random number in C. It has rand() and srand() function in stdlib.h But it gives me very large number. But I want only number b/w 1 to 10. So, is it possible and if yes then how? If is possible to generate character from a-z randomly.

Comment: `rand() % 10 + 1` but watch out for bias

Comment: Many duplicates on SO already. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-entire-range, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202687/in-c-how-do-i-get-a-specific-range-of-numbers-from-rand

Comment: vote to close... duplicate of [insert your favorite stack overflow C rand() question here]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the modulo operator to cut down the result to the range you want. Doing `rand() % 10` will give you a number from 0 to 9, if you add 1 to it, i.e. `1 + (rand() % 10)`, you'll get a number from 1 to 10 (inclusive).

And before others complain, this may dilute the random distribution, nevertheless, it should work fine for simple purposes.

Comment: Also don't forget to seed the random number generator or you'll get the same sequence each time on some systems.

Comment: The OP already mentioned `srand` so I assume he knows about it.

Comment: The modulo operator gives you an answer depending on the least significant bits, which in some RNGs are a lot less random than the most significant.  I'd rather go with division.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo (%) has some bias in it.

Slightly preferred is to scale the random number:

```
int aDigit = (int) (((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX+1)) * 9 + 1);
printf("%d", aDigit);
```

Breaking it down:

```
((double)rand() / RAND_MAX)
```

will generate a double between 0.0 and 0.99999

```
* 10
```

turns that to a number 0.0 to 9.9999.

```
+ 1;
```

turns that into 1.0 - 10.999

```
(int)
```

turns that into 1-10, which is what you asked for.

Comment: That approach has bias too.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746814/create-a-random-number-less-than-a-max-given-value/3746930#3746930